# How to output only the overlapping region of two files?

Tags: genome, interval

I have two files of genomic coordinates. I am trying to output only the overlapping region of fileA if it intersects with fileB. Not the original fileA coordinates.

fileA

```
chr1 25 50
chr1 75 200
```

fileB

```
chr1 10 60
chr1 80 90
```

desired output

```
chr1 25 50
chr1 80 90
```

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example using `dput` so we can help you. All you need to do is run `dput(fileA)` in R and, paste the output in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

[bedtools](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is my go-to program for operations on genomic intervals. In particular, the [bedtools intersect](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) operation is what you're looking for here.

```
$ cat fileA
chr1    25      50
chr1    75      200
$ cat fileB
chr1    10      60
chr1    80      90
$ bedtools intersect -a fileA -b fileB                                                           
chr1    25      50
chr1    80      90
```

Make sure that the values are separated by tabs rather than spaces, or bedtools will have trouble reading the files.